# How to escape from the bracket when writing Objective-C with Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I find writing Objective-C with Xcode sometimes could be painful when trying to escape from the bracket,

like I have to use the mouse or the direction key  <kbd>Right</kbd> to continue after entering `[UIView alloc]`.

Is there another way? <kbd>Tab</kbd> is not working :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Xcode is inserting the close bracket (`]`) for you, after your cursor. That happens because you have “Enable type-over completions” turned on in Xcode's preferences:

[image: preferences]

One way to handle this is by **typing a close bracket when your cursor is at the close bracket**. Because “Enable type-over completions” is turned on, Xcode will not insert another close bracket. It will just move the cursor past the existing close bracket. Try it! When you want to “escape from the bracket”, just type the bracket.

Another way to handle this is by turning off the “Enable type-over completions” setting. If you turn it off, Xcode will not insert the close bracket for you, so you'll have to type the close bracket, but you won't have to “escape from the bracket” because there's no bracket to escape from.

Comment: thanks, just found if I input the `]` last bracket myself, I will just jump out of it, no need to press the Right Key now :D it's been silly that I never try that myself

Answer (score 0):

No way around this as the autocomplete feature puts the cursor behind the close bracket to continue typing the method call. If this feature is turned off you can just type the closed bracket to finish the method call.

Comment: I found as @rob described, we could jump out of this by entering the last `]` myself, even when the autocompletion is one